# Torch: RNN clones run out of GPU memory

Tags: lua, torch, lstm

Karpathy's [char-rnn](https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn/blob/master/util/model_utils.lua#L113) (based on Wojciechz learning_to_execute) uses a common RNN hack:

- clone a prototype network as many times as there are time steps per sequence
- share the parameters between the clones

I can watch my 5GB GPU memory run out when I clone 217 times (the threshold is likely lower), resulting in this:

`lua
opt/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/File.lua:270: cuda runtime error (2) : out of memory at /mounts/Users/student/davidk/opt/torch/extra/cutorch/lib/THC/THCStorage.cu:44`

The problem is the `clone_many_times()` function (linked above). The clones seem to point to the same physical parameters storage in the prototype, but for some reason it still explodes.

Has anyone encountered this and/or have an idea how to train really long sequences?

(Same question asked here: https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn/issues/108)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the model, I had to increase memory capacity on the GPUs. With Sun's Grid Engine, use `-l h_vmem=8G` for 8 GB

Otherwise, you can try [torch-rnn](https://github.com/jcjohnson/torch-rnn). It uses Adam for optimization and hard-codes the RNN/LSTM forward/backward passes for space/time efficiency. This also avoids headaches with cloning models.